# Calling AJAX request as a callback of another function

Tags: jquery, ajax, callback

From all the answers I find on the web it sounds like this should be so simple, but I can't figure it out for the life of me...

I'm running a jQuery each function on an object on the page and then attempting to call an AJAX request as a callback of that function. Sample of my code below:

```
$("#cda").submit(function(e) {

e.preventDefault();

 var form = $(this);
 var url = form.attr('action');

 uploadCDADocs(function(){
   $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: url,
      data: form.serialize(),
      success: function(data)
      {
          alert(data);
      }
   });
 });

});

function uploadCDADocs(callback){

 $('input[name="cda-docs[]"]').each(function(){
   var file = $(this)[0].files[0];

   if(file){
     uploadMultipleFiles(file);
   }

 });

 callback();

}
```

As far as my understanding goes, the code should run everything in uploadCDADocs first and only then run the AJAX request once everything is done.

Currently however, the AJAX is being run at the same time as the code in myFunction is being run. What am I doing wrong?

I've also tried using $.when.then and that didn't work either. I'm stuck.

P.S. - All functions are working properly, I just can't get them to run in order.

Comment: Seems your function `uploadMultipleFiles` does asynchrnous stuff. What does the function look like?

Comment: Shouldn't need to do both operations if you use FormData API and send whole form including files

Comment: @Klaassiek uploadMultipleFiles uses the Dropbox API to upload files, so yes async. Is this the issue? How would I make sure that the uploadMultipleFiles functions are all done before calling the AJAX?

Comment: The dropbox api has a callback for when stuff is done. You could pass your callback to that function, but only fire it when all files are uploaded, so `if(currentFileIndex === (allFiles.length - 1)){myCallback();}`